# The impact of an arbitrary vector field on a smooth function

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function on a smooth manifold $M$. It is clear that if $f$ is constant on $M$ then $Xf=0$ for every smooth vector field $X\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$. I claim that the converse is also true; that is, i claim that if $Xf=0$ for every $X\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ then $f$ is constant. But, unfortunately, i can`t prove the converse. I appreciate if anyone gives me a hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $M$ is not connected, for example $[0,1] \cup [3,4]$, then there are functions $f$ which are not globally constant but only piecewise. So you might should add some conditions about $M$ to your claim.

Comment: Yes, i guessed that too. I may add that any two charts of $M$ must intersect. What about this extra condition? @SteffenPlunder

Comment: You mean there is an atlas of $M$ so that any two charts intersect. That is a rather awkward condition. You have [$X(f)=0$ for all vectorfields $X$ $\iff$ $f$ is locally constant]. Further [$f$ is locally constant $\impliedby$ $f$ is constant], but "$\implies$" only holds here if $M$ is connected. The correct condition for your statement is that $M$ is connected.

Comment: You definitely don't want to say any two charts must intersect.  This is very difficult to achieve even in a good situation. Why not assume $M$ is connected?

Comment: Ok but i do not know how to make a proof of this statement. How can i prove that the connectedness guarantees that the local constancy implies the global constancy.

Comment: That's exactly what connectedness is good for. Fix a point $p_0\in M$ and consider $S=\{p\in M: f(p)=f(p_0)\}$. What can you show about $S$?

Comment: oh yes, i got it. I proved that $S$ is both open and closed (clopen) and therefore (by the connectedness of $M$) $S$ must be the entire manifold. This is a very good idea. Thanks alot :)